# Python not adding text to a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-idle

Python does not adds text to file (although file is created) when run inside IDLE. But if run directly by using cmd or double clicking the file, it works fine. What might be the problem?
Code -

```
f = open('ERROR.txt', 'a')
f.write("hello")
f.close
```

I am using python 3 on windows 10.
Note: this is not duplicate. All other questions end by closing the file, but in my case, I already have closed the text file.

Comment: put code inside a try...except block to catch possible exceptions.

Comment: @FatemehKarimi Already done. No errors.

Comment: Maybe the file is created in a different directory (the default directory from which IDLE starts)? Can you try with an absolute file path?

Comment: @DanielJunglas, it would have been possible but as I mentioned, a blank file is still created in that directory.

Comment: `f.close` does not close the file; you need `f.close()`. You see text when you double-click the program because the file gets closed when the Python process terminates. You don't see text when you run the code inside IDLE because Python is still running. To avoid these kinds of errors, *as well as other problems*, you should use a `with` block to manage the file instead of trying to call `.close` yourself.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yeah you are right but it is already answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
f = open('ERROR.txt', 'a')
f.write("hello")
f.close()
```

Well, the problem is that f.close() is method of file class, and you call f.close instead of function. Try this code above

Another question, if you run your code does the file contain any text?

Comment: Thanks. I was making such a silly mistake. LOL. Good catch.

Comment: It is okay making mistakes